# Convergence of Cauchy sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to find out what is wrong with the proof that all convergent sequence of functions is uniformly convergent and the limit function is continuos. It basically follows from these theorems:

I can only post 2 links so please refer to the comment:

Every convergent sequence is Cauchy Sequence:[1]

All Cauchy sequence converges uniformly and its limit continuous[2],[3]

The proposition and theorem used:[4],[5]

I found a couterexample for a sequence of function $f_n$
$$f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow R$$
$$f_n=x^n$$
which  converges to $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1(x=1)
\\  0 (0\leq x<1)
\end{matrix}\right.$

which is not continuous

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/clp5C.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zCS8W.jpg
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/buGca.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Mft.jpg
  [5]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7TMwr.jpg

Comment: You are using the one word "convergent" to mean different things. That's the problem.

Comment: You sort of change the metric between some steps. This is not a good idea... in that, it breaks the whole reasoning.

Comment: @zhw:Can you elaborate more? The metric space in  [2],[3] contains points that are continuous functions from E to E'(E is compact, E's is complete), and metric D=max{d'(f(p),g(p)):p is a point in E}, while [1] applies for all metric space so I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Your sequence of functions does not converge in the metric D that you mention. It converges pointwise on $[0,1].$

Comment: @billy9797 But your sequence does not converge (nor is metric) in the complete space $F$ of continuous functions from $E$ to $E'$, for the norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty$. It converges pointwise, which is not the same... I.e., you need convergence wrt $\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty$ in $F$, but you only have convergence pointwise (outside of $F$).

Comment: @Clement How about we let the metric space contains the points that are functions from E=[0,1] to E'=[0,1]. Does the same reasoning still apply?

Comment: You will definitely not be able to prove the theorem saying that the limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous, then. (Specifically, no uniform convergence.)

Comment: @Clement how come not? Following [2], the sequence being Cauchy should imply,by the proposition, uniform convergence

Comment: But why is your sequence Cauchy? (One hypothesis fails along the line... for instance, why is your sequence actually convergent for the sup norm? have you tried to check what $\sup_{x\in[0,1)} \lvert x^n - 0\rvert$ was, just to have a sense of what was going on?). You use convergence of the sequence to get "Cauchy-ness," but neither of the two hold for the norm you want.

Comment: @Clement ok yes that sequence doesn't converge. I really did mistaked on the metric(thought it was the real number). So the line of reasoning is correct and the problem lies in the counter-example, is that correct? Specifically:all convergent sequence of functions in the defined metric space is uniformly convergent and the limit function is continuos?